# syntax error near unexpected token `(' writing bash function

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, docker

I have

```
testapi() { docker-compose -f /home/me/projects/api/docker-compose.yml run -e "API_BRANCH=${1-master}" --rm api_test ;}
```

It causes error:

```
$ src
bash: /home/me/.bash_profile: line 56: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/me/.bash_profile: line 56: `testapi() { docker-compose -f /home/me/projects/api/docker-compose.yml run -e "API_BRANCH=${1-master}" --rm api_test ;}'
```

Running yields help message:

```
$ testapi
Run a one-off command on a service.

For example:

    $ docker-compose run web python manage.py shell
```

Any help appreciated, ty

Comment: Works for me. What's your bash version?

Comment: $ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Does it work with a space before the parentheses?

Comment: no
bash: /home/me/.bash_profile: line 56: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/me/.bash_profile: line 56: `testwebapi () { docker-compose -f /home/me/work_projects/webapi/docker-compose.yml run -e "WEBAPI_BRANCH=${1-master}" --rm webapi_test ;}'

Comment: Do you have an alias defined of the same name as the function?

Answer (score 8):

You have defined an alias of the same name as the function. The alias gets expanded (as the profile is sourced in an interactive shell where aliases work) which makes the function definition invalid.

Comment: This was it! I couldn't figure out why just one of my function definitions couldn't be sourced unless I changed the syntax to `function foo { ...`

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly embarrassed to admit I had several moments of panic about having to modify years' worth of Bash scripts because the `function` syntax had changed in Bash 5.x.something. That is *not* the case here.

[The accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1099970/73744) nails the explanation, but I had to see it with my own eyes to believe it. Here's a contrived (no-op) example:

```bash
alias ls='ls -F'

ls() { command ls "$@"; }
# result: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

ls () command ls "$@"; }
# same: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Which is seen by the shell as:

```bash
ls -F() command ls "$@"; }
# result: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Any of *these* will work without error, though, since the alias is only expanded when it comes *first* on the command line:

```bash
function ls { command ls "$@"; }
function ls() { command ls "$@"; }
function ls () { command ls "$@"; }
```

Based on some light testing, it seems this behavior is *only* triggered when using the first form (no `function` keyword) and the function name exists already as a shell alias. If it's the name of an existing *function*, no problem, just redefines the function. If it's the name of an existing executable *disk file* in the search path, that's allowed, too, with the caveat that you need to use `command` as above to prevent endless recursion.

Odd that I'd never noticed this behavior before, because it seems like maybe the parser should keep going if it sees `<alias><optional whitespace><open paren>`, without expanding `<alias>`. Maybe it'll be fixed in Bash 6.0, who knows!